# Top to bottom multicolcolumn command?

Tags: lists, multicol

With the `multicol` package, you can insert `\LRmulticolcolumn` or `\RLmulticolcolumn` to get the items to appear from left-to-right/right-to-left but I'm looking for one that let me arrange the items from top to bottom.

Something like:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Instead of:

1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9

MWE:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\LRmulticolcolumn
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[label=]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `tasks` package is what you need.

To customize the skip between rows, just use the option `after-item-skip={...}`. Of course, you can put this option in the `\settasks` if all your tasks environments have the same skip.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format={\ignorespaces}, label-offset=0pt, label-width=0pt}

\begin{document}
Default vertical skip is inserted between rows of items:
    \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task 1
        \task 2
        \task 3
        \task 4
        \task 5
        \task 6
        \task 7
        \task 8
        \task 9
    \end{tasks}

Customized vertical skip is inserted between rows of items:
    \begin{tasks}[after-item-skip={30pt}](3)
        \task 1
        \task 2
        \task 3
        \task 4
        \task 5
        \task 6
        \task 7
        \task 8
        \task 9
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an equivalent parameter in the tasks package for [itemsep=<insert number>pt]? I'm using that for multicols at the moment to add blank spaces between items.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo Of course, there is, see my renewed answer. Thank you for accepting it.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo Please also note that I put `\ignorespaces` in the `counter-format={...}` to avoid `Overfull \hbox`es.